# PHP: How to run a Batch-Script in the background [Windows]

Tags: php, mysql, windows, batch-file

I've got a simple question:

How can I **run a batch-script in the background** on a **windows** machine? I need to establish a database connection with MySQL over XAMPP. For this, I need to **run "mysql_start.bat"** and the problem is, that the following code **stops executing** on the exec-command of PHP (I think it waits until the script is finished).

```
exec("cmd /c C:\\xampp\\mysql_start.bat > tmp.txt 2>&1");
```

*Hint: Redirecting the output isn't necessary, I just have tried it, but also didn't work.*

I haven't found any other possibilties to start MySQL.

Hopefully someone can help me.

Yours Michael.

Comment: Web code shouldn't generally have to start the database server, it should already be running...

Comment: Did you try to redirect both stdout and stderr? `exec('program.exe > NUL 2> NUL')`

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara: I know. It's just a project for school. I'm not running on a server. But I have to start the process though ...   awons: As you can see in my code example, I've already tried to redirect it into tmp.txt - no success. (I don't think there's a difference between NUL and a simple txt file.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Covert your batch file into windows executable using "Bat_to_exe converter" and just give the path removing "cmd /c" as parameters to exec().

Also use exception handling methods or "die" to check if the function returns any error.